# What does mov cx, 02001Q mean in assembly

Tags: nasm

I'm doing an analysis of the shellcode found at http://www.shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-211.php

I was wondering what this particular instruction does:

```
mov cx, 02001Q
```

I know it moves a value into cx, but I'm not sure what the Q stands for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [NASM docs](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html);

> NASM allows you to specify numbers in a variety of number bases, in a variety of ways: you can suffix H or X, D or T, Q or O, and B or Y for hexadecimal, decimal, octal and binary respectively

In other words, `02001Q` means 2001 octal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll have a closer look at the manual next time.